# terminate a USBdetector Thread using monitor from pyudev

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, pyudev

I have a python script that I'm running on a remote device. There will be two different threads created. The first thread is created to monitor for USB connections to the device.

```
class USBDetector(threading.Thread):
    ''' Monitor udev for detection of usb '''

    def run(self):
        ''' Runs the actual loop to detect the events '''
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
        self.monitor.start()
        for device in iter(self.monitor.poll, None):
            if device.action == 'add':
                # some action to run on insertion of usb
```

I've tried to insert a break statement if a global variable state changes. But it didn't work. something simple like

```
if TERMINATE == True:
    break
```

I looked at https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pyudev.html and through the reading it looks like this section of code

```
for device in iter(self.monitor.poll, None):
            if device.action == 'add':
            # some function to run on insertion of usb
```

is an endless loop, unless a timeout is inserted instead of None. I want to kill the thread when the other thread ends. If I give the quit command for my main thread, this usbdetector just keeps running. Any suggestions on how to stop it?

(UPDATE)

Hey,

sorry I went with a low tech way of solving my problem for now.

If anyone knows how to break out of this for loop without the need of a second loop, let me know

```
def run(self):
        ''' Runs the actual loop to detect the events '''
        global terminate
        self.rmmod_Module()
        self.context = pyudev.Context()
        self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
        self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
        self.monitor.start()
        count = 0
        while not terminate:
            count = count + 1
            print count
            for device in iter(partial(self.monitor.poll, 3), None):
                if device.action == 'add':
                     # some function to run on insertion of usb
```

obviously I have the for loop nested in a while loop waiting for terminate to be true. Its simple and works, however would still like to know if there is a way to kick out of the for device in iter() loop.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the direct answer you are looking for. Instead of synchronously monitoring the USB ports by polling, why not use asynchronous callbacks as seen in the following [pyudev monitoring device guide](https://pyudev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html#monitoring-devices) under section Asynchronous monitoring¶.

```
monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by('block')
def log_event(action, device):
   if 'ID_FS_TYPE' in device:
       with open('filesystems.log', 'a+') as stream:
           print('{0} - {1}'.format(action, device.get('ID_FS_LABEL')), file=stream)

observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(monitor, log_event)
observer.start()
```

From the code snippet you may receive multiple callbacks for a single USB device action, as it may recognise a single USB device as multiple devices. Putting this all together now you could do something as the following.

```
class USBDetector():
''' Monitor udev for detection of usb '''

def run(self):
    ''' Runs the actual loop to detect the events '''
    self.context = pyudev.Context()
    self.monitor = pyudev.Monitor.from_netlink(self.context)
    self.monitor.filter_by(subsystem='usb')
    self.observer = pyudev.MonitorObserver(self.monitor, self.usbDeviceEventHandler)
    self.observer.start()

def usbDeviceEventHandler(self, action, device):
    if device.action == 'add':
       # some function to run on insertion of usb
```

You may get multiple callbacks for a single usb action, so you could implement thread locking with Thread.lock() and accessing and editing a time variable and only accept new callbacks every second. I hope this helps, sorry for the late reply.